# Moving along a fixed array points with set speed or distance AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, math, trigonometry, bezier

so I have an array of points that show a dot-to-dot of various letters. This was done with bezier calculation on the letters(Which I'm not terribly familiar with).

My problem is that I now need to make an equal distance between each point of the array. So rather gaps on the straight section and many points on tight curves. I instead need one uniform unit every set distance(Lets say 5 pixels). So using the original Array how can I set an equal spacing between the points?

I've been ceaselessly amazing myself with how many wrong answers I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Senocular has a class that could help you with this. It's called Path here: http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/drawing/Path.as

It allows you to draw a path, so you can replace your drawing api commands with the same commands from his (or if you haven't plotted out each letter, plot it out) but it has a length getter and a pointAt getter so you can get the length (approximately) then gets points along the path.